# Where is the preview tab on Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: javascript, css, ide, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 2 on a Windows PC, and have a tab to preview the page on IE, and another to preview on Firefox.
But I switched to Aptana 3 and I don't know if there's no preview or I just not founding it.
And yes I did some research on stackoverflow and on aptana website, and on google too, and I have no answer.
Now I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on a Mac, and I'd like to preview my page on safari on a embed browser inside the IDE.

How I set it up to preview with other browsers.

If there's no way to do that, how people do to edit files and preview then? Editing CSS is like a pain, editing a thing like 1 pixel, and saving and switching to browser window, and refreshing the page. Would be awesome if exist a splited screen with live preview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Side-by-Side Previewing

By default, previewing opens in a new tab. You can modify this to see your source and your preview side-by-side.

#### Setting Previews

If you wish, you can have your source and preview side-by-side

1. Press the Preview button in the toolbar, The preview window launches
2. Drag the preview window by the top tab to the left, right, bottom, or top of the editor area, depending on how you wish to split the screen.
3. Saving the original source file updates the preview.

[image: Ilustration]

Result:
[image: Result]

> Source: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Side-by-Side+Previewing

Thanks `Ingo Muschenetz` for pointing this.

Comment: I answered myself and made the picture composition to keep the answer inside the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

There is a blue square with what looks like a eye inside. It's between the 'Aptana Start Page' and 'Open Terminal' icons in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a side-by-side preview. See the document here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Side-by-Side+Previewing

Answer (score 0):

*There is a blue square with what looks like a eye inside. It's between the 'Aptana Start Page' and 'Open Terminal' icons in the toolbar.* : True but before you must have *Toolbar* visible. By default, at my Aptana, I dit not have the Toolbar but I have the same problem as *Vitim.us*.
So, 1) *Windows* --> *Show Toolbar* and 2) the solution of *Michael Bunch*.